# Is it possible to create constants in Progress-4GL?

Tags: constants, openedge, progress-4gl

Good afternoon,
Is it possible to create constants in Progress-4GL?

The same question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464041/final-const-keyword-equivalent-in-progress-4gl), but there the question is based on object oriented programming (which I'm not doing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `constant` keyword in ABL.

The simplest way to create constant values is using static properties. These are available in any code, even procedural.

```
class ConstantValues:
  define static public PI as decimal initial 3.14159 get.
end class.
```

You could add a private setter and do the assignment in the static constructor, instead of the `initial` value.

If you can't or don't want to use this approach, you can use preprocessors. If you need these values shared then define the preprocessors in includes and use those in your programs (even classes).

But that's - to me - more work than it needs to be if you're creating new constant values.

Answer (score 2):

Even if not a constant and also possibly quite old school you can define precompiler statements that can work as a constant.

There's a possibility for global (`&GLOBAL-DEFINE`) and not global (`&SCOPED-DEFINE`)

Its also possible to undefine, check defined and other basic things.

These are define on compilation time so they cannot be changed dynamically when the program is running.

```
&SCOPED-DEFINE const1 1
&GLOBAL-DEFINE const2 hello

DISPLAY {&const1} "{&const2}".
```